# In DDD, are entities allowed to use the database for search, indexing etc.?

Tags: domain-driven-design

It is (was?) considered best practices when it come to web programming to let the database do the 'heavy lifting', when possible. For example, I have a contact list, and it consists of many emails addresses and name. Each email must be unique, so one potentially bad solution for an active record model (Eloquent) is this case will be:

```
 public function addEmail($name, $address)
 {
    if ($this->where('name', $name)->where('address', $address)->count() > 0)
  {
  throw new \Exception("Name and email already exists!");
  }

 // perform add new logic

 }
```

If what I have understood is correct, I shouldn't be doing this -- that the entities should be plain data objects, and unable to make calls out to the DB.

In that case, how should I enforce that bit of validation? Use a service, or load in all the addresses for the `ContactList`, or move it somewhere else (an `AddNewEmailToConactList` service?)

Comment: Actually, what you're describing (the "anemic data pattern") is [sometimes considered an antipattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Note that DDD is not a development technique; it is a *design technique.* You're *allowed* to do anything you want in software development, so long as it solves the problem in a way that is easily understood, maintainable, and has adequate performance characteristics.

Comment: I've clarified my question; I know that the example code is considered 'bad' by DDD standards. The question is - do I have to load in all the existing email addresses that the contact list have, and check them in-memory without the help of the database for it to be considered 'correct'?

Comment: There is no such thing as "correct."  There is only that which best meets your specific requirements and tradeoffs.

Comment: True, let's try "what are the possible recommendations or alternatives", or will that be too subjective for SO?

Comment: What technique do you think would best solve your problem?

Comment: Ok, just to clarify - I am not looking for an argument. Usually, StackExhange's policy is that if the question is going to be subjective, then usually it's a no-go, that's the intent. Anyway thanks for your perspective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44802/discussion-between-extrakun-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 1):

You have a look at the business-rules that govern your domain, and you find the one that will cause you a problem, and you validate it at the point where you might break it.

So if the rule is *There can be no duplicate email addresses in the contact list* then you would validate it when you add the new `Entry` to the `ContactList`.

The `ContactList` itself will most likely have a method `AddNewEntry` which will do the check, and the `ContactList` either *is* or *has* a database table that it can query to check if the name already exists.

It's perfectly valid to have multiple copies of the same email addresses in this case; they just can't all go on the `ContactList`. There could even be multiple `ContactLists` in which case the above code would still work, with each list checking its own contents. But it really depends on the exact domain you're working from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; how could an entity query a database, if it is to be just a plain data object?

Comment: You should use an UseCase to enforce the validation, for example `AddNewEntry`, this could be part of your service. He can talk to your external DB system via an adapter to avoid being tangled with the DB itself, and in there you can enforce the validation any way you want.

You could retrieve the ContactList and check that the email is not part of the received list, or try asking the adapter to add the email to the database, and check if it returns an error.

You end up with a plain object entity, your database could do the heavy lifting if you want to. Check out http://bit.ly/2a1px8t